# What is the correct way of representing double in C#?

Tags: c#, double, suffix

I am using the first way and my new company is using the second way.

```
double x = 1.99; 

double y = 9.02D;
```

Which one is correct and why?

If both is correct, then how to use this is in different scenarios?

Comment: it is just redundant to specifying the d since there is the ".". I've se other company inventing "rules" but, the real rulers is always the language.

Comment: Thanks guys for all positive results.

Comment: Up voted everybody . Have a great day for all. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @nandu.com, you forgot to upvote me (just saying).

Comment: Is it so... I am very sorry. I will correct it at once.

Comment: but perhaps you shouldn't have asked here, but in a private message or chat . it may give bad reputation for both of us :(

Comment: Odds are good neither is correct; are you sure this is supposed to be a double and not a decimal?

Comment: @Eric - I thought decimal represented as 
`decimal x = 1.99M;`

Comment: @nandu.com: Correct. When I see a quantity like "1.99" I automatically think "price" and not "scientific quantity", which is why I suspect that you intend this to have decimal arithmetic semantics and not double-precision semantics. What is the constant being used for?

Comment: @Eric - I deleted a old reply.. Constants for measurement sizes of bearings , it often needs 90% calibration . even a small error would be costly :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> By default, a real numeric literal on
>   the right-hand side of the assignment
>   operator is treated as double.
>   However, if you want an integer number
>   to be treated as double, use the
>   suffix d or D, for example: Copy
>
> double x = 3D;

So there is no difference between `double x = 1.99;` and `double y = 9.02D;`

Answer (score 7):

I would say the way your company is doing it is probably safer.  The D after the value 9.02 forces the <strike>integer</strike> numeric (real) value 9.02 to be treated as a double.

Comment: 9.02 is not an integer value.

Comment: `9.02` is not an integer value

Comment: I think Jana is new to programming, I am impressed by her urge to answer. +1 for her first answer(I was going through your profile :) )

Comment: I'm actually the one who did the correction since I felt sorry for her.

Comment: @Elite Gentleman - the quality of Elite People. :)Making correction and feeling sorry.  I think Jana too will approve :)

Answer (score 4):

The `double y = 9.02D;`, the suffix `D` converts your numeric (real) value to a double. This is used if you want your integer value to be converted to a double or to specify that your value is *indeed* a double.

E.g.

```
double d = 3D;
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

PS. As Sehe mentioned, this would convert your variable `d` to a double.

```
var d = 3D;
```

without the `D` suffix, `d` would have been an `int`.

Comment: Or perhaps more convincingly `var d = 3D`

Answer (score 4):

A floating-point literal without a suffix is a `double`, so there's really no difference between `1.99` and `1.99D` (or `1.99d`) - except that the latter form makes it explicit that this is, indeed, a `double`. So it's a matter of style, really. In general, you should of course stick to your company's style (unless you have a really compelling reason that the style is "wrong" - in which case you should convince the company to change the style, rather than just silently violating it yourself ;-)  ).

Comment: Thanks - but although I phrased it humoristically I was serious about it too; the only thing that is worse than a bad coding style is a lack of coding style or the mix of different coding styles :-)

Comment: Yes, You are correct. My previous company suffers a lot because of bad coding style or better not ensuring that all programmers follow the same code style.   Any way, Nice message to all programmers. thanks

Answer (score 4):

For a simple declaration, it seems extraneous.

The 'd' suffix could be useful in situation such as this:

```
int n = 10;
double a = n / 3; // 3
double a = n / 3d; // 3.333..
```

But it's poor form anyway, since the second division depends on implicit cast of (n) to a double before doing the division.

Same reasoning if you were passing a floating constant to a method that happened to have two overloads:

```
void foo(float bar);
void foo(double bar);
```

you could distinguish the version you want to call by calling:

```
X.foo(3.0D);
```

Again, not the best form.

As for simple declaration, there's no speed advantage since the compiler will likely optimize it anyway.

(borrowed example from [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141312-double-declaration.html))

Comment: Explaining with use of a function is more understandable. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Stylistically, you generally only need to add a 'd' or a 'D' when you want an integer literal to be a double:

`double d = 1d;`

So in your example, making `double d = 1.99d`, is pointless, because the compiler will already assign 1.99 to a double. Not to mention when you declared the `d`, it's type was double as well.

In general, you don't need to add `d` or `D` to double literals.

However, in your case the 2nd one is correct, because it's the style chosen by the people who are paying you, and in the end, that's what really matters.

Comment: Thanks Alan. :) +1 as I put the same thought to my colleague. :) Great people think alike .

Answer (score 2):

Suffix d is important while using reflection and other dynamic usage to enforce complier to consider the number as double instead of integer where double can have number without decimal. 1.99 is perfect double.

While using reflection using 1 will give conversion error.

```
PropertyInfo p...

p.SetValue(obj, 1)
```

will throw error but

```
p.SetValue(obj, 1D)
```

will work correctly.

```
var x = 1;
```

x is int

```
var x = 1D;
```

x is double.

Comment: Sorry I typed this in iPhone, no formatting supported in iPhone.

Comment: +1 for Akash for his refractoring(unique way of explaining my doubt). Thanks :)